# I have a navigation bar that becomes fixed when you scroll down. It doesn't work unless you're scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I figured out how to make it fixed, etc:

HTML:

```
<div id="header_nav">
      <nav>
        <ul class="navi">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
... Stack overflow wont let me add more code, but there are more links, etc
```

JS:

```
var elementPosition = $('#header_nav').offset();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
    $('#header_nav').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
  } else {
    $('#header_nav').css('position','static');
  }
});
```

My navigation bar is supposed to have hover effects when you hover over each selection. The hover effects only work after the transition to it being fixed at the top is complete. The links are also not clickable. I tried playing around with the JS but I can't figure it out. It's as if the bar is only saved as an image until you scroll all the way down.

Full code is here: http://liveweave.com/XGPWVt

Comment: @CodeiSir  http://liveweave.com/XGPWVt Can you try this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `<div id="wrapper">` section inside the `<header>` tag.

Updated example: http://liveweave.com/aGN9YV

Comment: Yassss. Can you please explain why this changes things? 

And also, if I make the window more narrow, the background image shrinks so that it doesn't get all stretched out. How can I also shrink the background image "area" (the white part), which I assume will keep my name vertically centered?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change static to relative as well

Comment: There's a problem. When I'm fullscreen, as soon as I scroll up to NAME, it jumps to the bottom of the background picture.